# Assign specific content of a .txt file into a python variable

Tags: python

I have a txt file and i want to assign a specific word, i.e a number, from inside the text file. e.g the content of the file is the following:

```
`/mydata/data/data1/patient1009654/T1w/Diff/filea.nii.gz:data_fixed_new.nii.gz => MI 0.379897`
```

I want to get the number 0.379897 and store it as a variable. Till now, i am doing something like this:

```
import mmap
f = open('/Users/glazar0/Documents/HCPtest/subject100307/result.txt')
s = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    if s.find('MI') != -1:
    my_var = f.read(f.seek(f.tell()))
```

but it gives a NULL output.

Comment: So what have you tried, and what exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: I only know how to open a .txt file. I don't know what to do afterwards.

Comment: ...`.read` it?! [RTFM](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)!

Comment: yes i can read it also, but how can i choose a specific number from all of it?

Comment: Without **much** more context (for example: will there be multiple numbers in the file? Is there a specific file structure? How would *you* tell, from looking at it, what should be extracted?) that question is literally unanswerable. If it's "just" a text file consider regular expressions, otherwise (e.g. CSV, XML) use a specific parser.

Comment: Ok. The file is .txt and it will always contains 2 numbers. I want the second one. The structure of the file looks like this: /mydata/data/data1/patient1009654/T1w/Diff/filea.nii.gz : data_fixed_new.nii.gz => MI 0.379897

Comment: This is **not** a code-writing service. Make an effort, write some code and return with a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you *really* can't get anywhere.

Comment: i tried something. Take a look on my edit.

Comment: This would be much easier with a regular expression - e.g. https://regex101.com/r/iG6yK9/1. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html for implementation.

Comment: Ok i did it. Thank you very much. Guidelines was pretty much all i needed and regular expressions offered the solution. ;)

Comment: come on guys, please unvote my post. I fixed it

Comment: You *improved* it, but it's not *fixed*. *"it does not work"* is **not** a helpful problem description.

Comment: i fixed my question but still i cannot post new questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i did it like this and it works:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("(?<=MI\s)(\d+\.\d+)")
for i, line in enumerate(open('the_file.txt')):
    for match in re.finditer(pattern, line):
        var = (i+1, match.groups())
        my_conten = float(var[1][0])
```